# Disable festival from 'noticing' abbreviations, by editing .festivalrc

Tags: configuration, festival

The developers of the `festival` text-to-speech program do not seem to have been aware that DEC can stand for the [Digital Equipment Corporation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Equipment_Corporation) as easily as it can stand for December, and that SEP can stand for [Somebody Else's Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody_Else%27s_Problem).

I, for one, have never used DEC and SEP to refer to month names. Never once. In fact, since I began using `festival` to read things out and generally give my eyes a break, I've discovered that I hate all abbreviations, precisely because they're ambiguously un-meaningful, conveying an air of military-style deliberate obfuscation.

But, annoyingly, any time `festival` encounters these or similar two-letter and three-letter collocations (like ST, which more often means *Saint* or *Star Trek* than Street), it reads them out.

If I am going to listen to a text, I actually look hard for these abbreviations by means of regular expressions, so that I can un-abbreviate them. I don't want `festival` to get involved in that process.

But configuring festival requires lisp, much like `emacs`. Which scheme statement will allow me to totally disable this feature in the `.festivalrc`?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/festival/manual-1.4.1/festival_34.html) about **english_token_to_words** says that :

> Returns a list of words for NAME from TOKEN. This allows the user to
>   customize various non-local, multi-word, context dependent
>   translations of tokens into words. If this function is unset only the
>   builtin translation rules are used, if this is set the builtin rules
>   are not used unless explicitly called.

Maybe you can try to unset it. I am not familiar with this syntax, but it should look like :

```
(unset! english_token_to_words)
```

And if it's not enough, there's also a **token_to_word** wrapper :

```
(unset! token_to_words)
```

Comment: i tried unsetting these via the command line but got errors: the command i used was 'text2wave -eval '(unset! english_token_to_words)' -o hello.wav'. the error was
SIOD ERROR: unbound variable : unset!